# Selenium, SELECT tag with particular attributes

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I need to select all link elements which has `'aria-lable'` attribute, under id 'jsGrid_vgAllCases'. I first tried the following code, it will select all links under id='jsGrid_vgAllCases'

```
for link in driver.find_element_by_id('jsGrid_vgAllCases').find_elements_by_tag_name('a'):
    print(link.text)
```

I then tried this way

```
for link in driver.find_element_by_id('jsGrid_vgAllCases').find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@aria-label]'):
    print(link.text)
```

but it will select all links with attribute of 'aria-lable', even outside of id='jsGrid_vgAllCases'

Please advise how to write this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you could xpath like this :

```
//a[@aria-lable]
```

so basically it will point all the `a` tag which has `aria-lable` attribute.

and then use it like :

```
all_links = find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@aria-lable]")
```

Now all `all_links` is a list in Python. so you print it's size like this :

```
print(len(all_links ))
```

You can do many operations on this python list.

Answer (score -1):

```
for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='jsGrid_vgAllCases']//a[@aria-label]"):
    print(link.text)
```

This will work

Comment: sir, this is an unethical approach, you edited the original question and then gave your own answer without notifying the answerer. We don't entertain such thing here.

Comment: @cruisepandey 1000% with you. There are several users doing such things. What can we do against them?

Comment: OK, upvoted your answer :) You can also downvote his answers / questions. This is a really weird manner such users behave.

Comment: @Prophet : feel free to tag me in such post where OP behaves like this, I would gladly help you out too. Thank you for this !

Comment: Thanks, but I will not do this. I don't want to ask anyone to give me upvotes to answers I gave not to them. let's do something better: in case you see some interesting answer I gave - upvote it. In case it's something good, interesting, not just a simple locator / wait etc. issue. I will do the same to you, similarly what I do to other people here. We are not contestants or opponents, but companions. At least this is what we should be :)

Comment: @Prophet : Sure mate, I understand that. Why I was saying, is because sometimes OP delete their question as well, but if you have a upvote on your answer, OP won't be able to delete it, it's SO architecture. In this case I have not downvoted his answer, cause I don't do that. but he could delete his answer but not the question since my answer has one upvote.